# Ocultar campo no HTML com Bootstrap

Tags: html, html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, layout-responsivo

Como posso fazer com que um campo de texto em meu `HTML` fique oculto quando o usuário estiver visualizando pelo celular e apareça quando ele estiver visualizando pelo PC?

Comment: Neste caso voce vai ter que suar javascript para alterar a classe do elemento.

Answer (score 15):

## Utilize as classes de responsividade do Bootstrap

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

No seu caso, utilizar as classes `hidden-xs` para ocultar algo na resolução mobile e `visible-xs` para mostrar apenas em resolução mobile.

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    Elemento oculto para mobile
</div>
<div class="visible-xs">
    Elemento visível para mobile e oculto nas demais resoluções
</div>
```

## Configuração das resoluções no Twiter Bootstrap

- `lg` - Dispositivos grandes (desktops, **>= 1200px**)
- `md` - Dispositivos médios (desktops, **>= 992px && < 1200px**)
- `sm` - Dispositivos pequenos (tablets, **>= 768px && < 992px**)
- `xs` - Dispositivos extra pequenos (smartphones, **< 768px**)

Poderá combinar os prefixos `hidden-` ou `visible-` com qualquer uma das tags de resolução acima.

Comment: Pedro, nesse caso eu tenho que definir a resolução que ele deve ocultar ou existem algum mecanismo que identifica a resolução como sendo de um celular?

Comment: @KleberNunes alterei a resposta explicando cada tag.

Comment: Cara, se não fosse as frameworks, fazer uma coisa dessa ia ser muuito chato

Comment: Também acho mas graças aos frameworks acabei aprendendo mais e ficando independente deles para esses tipos de coisas.