# Espaçamentos entre inputs Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber como posso adicionar um espaçamento entre os `selects`, para melhor entendimento veja a **imagem** abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei com o css:

```
.col-md-4 {margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

Porém ficou esquisito, meu *código* `html` atualmente está assim:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select name="dia" class="form-control">
        <option>Selecione o dia</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select name="mes" class="form-control">
        <option>Selecione o mes</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select name="ano" class="form-control">
        <option>Selecione o ano</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aguardo respostas []'s

Comment: Opinião pessoal: não gosto de utilizar o bootstrap com todos os recursos dele, uso ele apenas como grid. Seria até mais "limpo" se você usasse apenas uma `div` para determinar a coluna e os elementos do formulário, já que estão um embaixo do outro, atribuir um `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma solução simples, como sou novato com Bootstrap, olhando o site vi que lá tem as opções `.col.xs-? .col-md-?`, apenas troquei de `.col-md` para `.col-xs` e ficou até mais bonito o design do site, ele encaixou os 3 selects vamos dizer que numa linha só.

Selecione o dia

```
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <select name="mes" class="form-control">
        <option>Selecione o mes</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <select name="ano" class="form-control">
        <option>Selecione o ano</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Utilize as classes do próprio `bootstrap` para fazer isso, nesse caso, deixe os itens do formulário dentro de uma div com a classe [form-group](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <select name="dia" class="form-control">
    <option>Selecione o dia</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <select name="mes" class="form-control">
    <option>Selecione o mes</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <select name="ano" class="form-control">
    <option>Selecione o ano</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua respostas, mas eu resolvi, usando `.col-xs` ao invés de `.col-md` assim os `selects` se encaixam certinho.

Comment: form-group é pra isto mesmo. acho que não tem necessidade de ter uma div so pra ela pode deixar na col-md-4

Comment: @GuilhermeGouveiaAlves quando você utiliza o `col-xs` você está definindo que sua `div` terá 4 colunas para a resolução extra small e caso  não definida a quantidade para as outras resoluções, será adotada 4 colunas para todas as resoluções. [Veja nessa resposta a definição de cada resolução do bootstrap](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103993/ocultar-campo-no-html-com-bootstrap/103996#103996)

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues tem razão, alterei conforme sua sugestão.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve colocar um `!important` no seu css. Desta maneira:

```
.col-md-4 {margin-bottom: 5px;!important}
```

Resultado: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando trabalhar com bootstrap, lembre-se disso. O CSS está basicamente pronto. Então, para editar o que já existe, precisa do `!important`

Comment: Ta certo, mas percebi um comportamento estranho, gostaria que modificasse apenas no responsivo, apenas no responsivo os selects se juntam.

Comment: Isso acontece porque o código está dentro de um @media (min-width: 992px).

Answer (score -3):

Bobagens meus caros

```
<div class="form-control" style="width:???px; margin-bottom:2px">
    <select runat="server" name="mes" id="mes">
        <option>Selecione o mes</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-control" style="width:???px; margin-bottom:2px">
    <select name="ano" id="ano">
        <option>Selecione o ano</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

vc pode colocar todas os inputs com `class= "input"` e dps botar no css `.input{margin-top: 5px}`