# Mostrar conteúdo na versão desktop e escondê-lo na versão mobile. E vice-versa

Tags: html, wordpress

possuo um formulário com duas características diferentes, uma para mobile e outra para desktop.
Não sei como configurar para que uma seja apresentada e outra ocultada dependendo se o site está no desktop ou no mobile.

Lendo algumas respostas aqui do fórum tentei o seguinte:

```
<!-- aparecer no desktop -->
<div class="mobile-hide">
  ------------------------------------------
  <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:1170px; text-align: center;">
    <?php get_template_part('inc_booking'); ?>
  </div>
  código do 1° formulário, sem necessidade de alteração 
  ------------------------------------------
</div>
<!-- /aparecer no desktop -->

<!-- aparecer no mobile -->
<div class="mobile">
  <div class="desktop-hide">
  ------------------------------------------
    <?php get_template_part('inc_booking'); ?>
  </div>
  código do 2° formulário, sem necessidade de alteração 
  ------------------------------------------
</div>
<!-- /aparecer no mobile -->
```

Mas as duas versões estão sendo apresentadas tanto no desktop quanto no mobile.

Comment: Não pode usar [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries)?

Comment: edtei a resposta para atender seu pedido no comentário. Faça um teste e me retorne o resultado.

Comment: Se você estiver usando [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) veja [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103993/ocultar-campo-no-html-com-bootstrap/103996#103996) resposta como é simples.

Answer (score 3):

trecho de código extraído da biblioteca bootstrap:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .hidden-xs {
        display: none!important
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px)and (max-width: 991px) {
    .hidden-sm {
        display: none!important
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px)and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .hidden-md {
        display: none!important
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .hidden-lg {
        display: none!important
    }
}
```

edit: coloquei a largura exata
hidden-xs: esconde para celulares (<768px);

hidden-sm: esconde para tablets  (≥768px);

hidden-md: esconde para desktops (>= 992px e < 1200px)

hidden-lg: esconde para desktops (>= 1200px)

informações também extraídas da documentação do bootstrap.

Veja mais em https://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Legal Diego, onde posso incluir o código do formulário dentro conteúdo que enviou?

Código Mobile:

<?php get_template_part('inc_booking'); ?>

Código Desktop:

<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:1170px; text-align: center;">
<?php get_template_part('inc_booking'); ?>
</div>

Comment: Em qualquer bloco ou folha de css.
Espero ter ajudado, abraços

Answer (score 0):

> Já que sua página é PHP....

```
<?php
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
// Qualquer dispositivo móvel (telefones ou tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
    echo ("<div class=\"mobile\"><div class=\"desktop-hide\">".get_template_part('inc_booking')."</div></div>");
}else{
    echo ("<div class=\"mobile-hide\"><div style=\"position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:1170px; text-align: center;\">".get_template_part('inc_booking')."</div></div>");
}
?>
```

[**Mobile_Detect.php**](http://mobiledetect.net/)

Comment: Obrigado Leo, onde posso incluir o código do formulário dentro conteúdo que enviou? 

Código Mobile: <?php get_template_part('inc_booking'); ?> 

Código Desktop: <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width:1170px; text-align: center;"> <?php get_template_part('inc_booking'); ?> </div>

Comment: Esse  get_template_part('inc_booking') é uma função né, então com javascript não vai rolar. Vou fazer com editar a resposta com PHP puro.