# Alterar conteúdo de acordo com o tamanho da tela

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Tenho um link com um texto que fica normal ao ser exibido no pc,porém, muito grande para celulares (onde eu iria usar só uma sigla).
Preciso de uma maneira de mudar o texto de acordo com o tamanho do display. 
Já procurei saber como escrever textos com css, pois desta forma basta usar media queries para exibir apenas o css que eu preciso em cada tamanho de tela, mas li que escrever textos com:

```
:before {
    content: "- ";
}
```

não é recomendado.
Me ajudem por favor, o site que estou desenvolvendo [é este aqui](http://minionu2017.esy.es/),quero modificar a aba "os comitês". Como é o primeiro site q estou criando, n sei mta coisa (inclusive js),então tem como fazer isso só com bootstrap, css e html?

Comment: O [boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com) possui classes que você pode utilizar para mostrar ou ocultar conteúdo de acordo com a resolução, veja [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103993/ocultar-campo-no-html-com-bootstrap/103996#103996) resposta.

Comment: E voce nao precisa escrever texto pelo CSS pra isso, basta definir o tamanho usando media query referente a classe. Ex:

@media(max-width: 900px){
   .classe{
   font-size: 10px;  
}
}

Comment: muito obrigado @PedroCamaraJunior era isso mesmo que eu pracisava

Comment: obrigado a todos que ajudaram

Answer (score 3):

Usando o *media query* você pode definir o controle do tamanho da tela e aplicar estilos conforme tal.

Ex: um `h1` meu eu uso `5em` em telas grandes, mas ficarão grande de mais no mobile, então basta usar o *media query* para diminuir o tamanho dele quando minha tela for menor que `1000px`

Então, para isso podemos usar vários *media query*.

```
max-width: 500px; 
max-width: 1000px;
```

E assim em diante, para ser aplicado vários estilos diferente

```
    @media(max-width: 500px){
    .texto{
        font-size: 10px;
        color: black;
    }
   }
```

https://jsbin.com/pocudi/2/edit?css,output

Comment: Poderia falar um pouco mais sobre como funcionam e se possível dar outros exemplos de uso?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/pocudi/2/edit?css,output

Comment: So testar o link a cima, deixando a janela do navegador maior e menor

Comment: Eu sei como funciona, mas não basta apenas uma resposta vaga, quanto mais completa sua resposta mais ela irá colaborar para que outras pessoas que a vejam possam compreende-la e aperfeiçoar-se assim. Portanto se puder deixar sua resposta melhor terei todo prazer em dar +1.

Comment: eu fiz um exemplo para que fosse auto explicativo, mas vamos la, usando o media query voce pode definir o controle do tamanho da tela e aplicar estilos conforme tal.

Ex: um h1 meu eu uso 5em em telas grandes, mas ficarao grande de mais no mobile, entao é so usar o media query para diminuir o tamanho dele quando minha tela for menor que 1000px.

Comment: Entao, para isso podemos usar varios media query. Max-width: 500px; Max-width: 1000px; e assim em diante, para ser aplicado varios estilos diferente

Comment: Adicione à sua resposta. :)

Comment: @ErlonCharles Pronto :D Obrigado pelo toque

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você gostaria de exibir somente uma sigla quando fosse no Celular, correto?

Se esse for o caso, você poderia simplesmente criar classes específicas de display em media queries. Por exemplo: você poderia ter uma classe `mobile` e/ou `desktop`.

Poderia deixar seu texto dessa forma:

```
<p>Texto a ser exibido no desktop. <span class="visible-mobile">Texto visível somente no celular</span>
</p>
```

Depois seria só montar o seu CSS de acordo:

```
.desktop {
    display: block; /* inline, inline-block */
}
.mobile {
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
    .desktop{
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile {
        display: block; /* ou inline, inline-block */
    }
}
```

Exemplo:

```css
.desktop {
  display: block;
  /* ou inline, inline-block */
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: block;
    /* ou inline, inline-block */
  }
}
```

```html
<p><span class="desktop">Texto a ser exibido no desktop.</span> <span class="mobile">Texto visível somente no celular</span>
</p>
```